# User control IDs not Being Recognized in Code-behind after Port to WAP

Tags: asp.net

I copied over all my files from my Web Site Project to the root of my new WAP project.  Now none of my user controls IDs in my .aspx pages are being recognized in the related code-behind pages and not sure why.

For example, our Master Page has the following user control referenced:

```
<%@ Register Src="Navbar.ascx" TagName="Navbar" TagPrefix="mc" %>
```

and in the Master Page it's being used:

```
<td id="tdNavBar"><mc:Navbar runat=server id="navbar"></mc:Navbar></td>
```

but now, some of the code in my Master.cs that was referencing navbar no longer knows about it.

Comment: And the problem is, I cannot create a designer file because of the reference problems with the user controls and custom controls.  It simply will not register them.

Comment: I realize when I try using Intellisense that pm is not a recognized TagName in the list to choose from when creating my tag

Answer (score 0):

If they're not recognised in your code behind file, double check that they have been declared in the .designer.cs file.  If they are not there, try manually adding them and see if that works correctly.

You might also want to try manually creating a new user control using the File --> New Item option to check that it isn't to do with when you copy and pasted the items in (i.e. they could have the wrong namespace, etc).

Comment: At the top of your master page code behind, try and type:
protected Your.Namespace.Navbar navbar;

i.e. put the declaration I mentioned in the .cs, not the .designer.cs file, then see if it works.

Comment: One more thing, I'm not sure if it's just in your question or in your code, but you have missed quotes around the runat=server part (should be runat="server").

Comment: Also, purely as a test, try and remove this:
<mc:Navbar runat="server" ...

and replace it with this:
<asp:PlaceHolder id="MyPlaceHolder" ...

Then in your code try and do this:
MyPlaceHolder.Controls.Add(
    LoadControl("~/Controls/Navbar.ascx"));

See if that works, or produces a more helpful error message.